# What is a common file/data format for a mesh (for FEM)?

Tags: finite-element, mesh, graph-theory

I'm developing an FEM simulation. For early testing, I will use simple self-written mesher and visualisation of the mesh graph. But I want to prepare my program to use data generated by an existing mesher and output it to existing visualisation tools.

**Is there a recommended (quasi-)standard for file format and internal data format for (FEM) meshes?**

Comment: Exodus II for reading in the mesh and VTK for writing output.

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is no, there is not a standard format. But there are some common ones, like Gmsh for input/output and VTK for output.

Before making a decision you need to find out what do you want to do. If you want to have your (small) program for a while, then you can pick the format that best suit to your taste and needs. If you are planning to change to a "bigger" program in the future, it would be a good idea to start managing their file formats right now. If you are planning to use commercial pre/post-processors then I suggest that you stick to their formats, since they "update" those with every new version and it might be a pain in the head.

Below, I list some (open source) options.

**Pre-processing**

- [Gmsh](http://gmsh.info/), with its [fileformat](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#File-formats)
- [FreeCAD](http://www.freecadweb.org/) as a preprocessor. This one creates [Calculix Input files](http://www.calculix.de/) that are compatible with [Abaqus](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/simulia/).

**Post-processing**

- Visualization with [Paraview](http://www.paraview.org/)/[Mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/). Then use [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf) file formats. You can check the Paraview user guide [here](http://www.paraview.org/paraview-downloads/download.php?submit=Download&version=v5.0&type=data&os=all&downloadFile=ParaViewGuide-CE-v5.0.0.pdf).
- You can also do post-processing in Gmsh.
- [Salome-Meca](http://www.salome-platform.org/) is another option for post-processing, it works fine with VTK.

Comment: I think VTK is the right format for me: 1. I can use it as input for the mesh and as output for post-processing. 2. There exists a library to handle it. 3. It seems to be common, for example gmesh can generate it. Are those assumptions ok?

Comment: **1.** You need to consider that the inclusion of material properties, BCs and constraints on your model. I am not completely sure how to implement these in VTK, but probably you can find a workaround. **2.** Yes, but it depends on the programming language of your choice. **3.** Yes, it is common. You can use directly [``vtk``](http://www.vtk.org/) (in C++, Java or Python), Mayavi, Paraview, VisIt or even [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/3dview/hhngciknjebkeffhafnaodkfidcdlcao) :P. And, yes, you can generate them in Gmesh, not sure about the physical groups, though.

Answer (score 3):

You might try either [Gmsh's MSH file format](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#File-formats) or [GAMBIT neutral file format](http://web.stanford.edu/class/me469b/handouts/gambit_write.pdf).

Comment: I use gmsh mesh files for personal projects as well, that format is easy to understand and replicate yourself

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a standard for this: [ISO/TS 10303](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303) (start with parts 1380 to 1386).

Prior to being hijacked by ISO, this initiative, which began back in the 1980s, was known as PDES/STEP. See https://www.pdesinc.org/index.html

But I don't believe anybody much uses it unless they are working in an environment where it is a mandatory requirement. A large number of international committees did an excellent job in subverting the original good intention, and produced a standard that attempts to cover everything from the describing the overall management structure of a company to the correct format for writing dates and times (and no, I'm not joking).

Answer (score 3):

The number of file formats for FEM is ridiculous, partly due to the fact that every software package implemented its own format in the past.

[image]

(From [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/927/).)

I've created [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) to alleviate the pain of converting between formats, so if you use any format supported by meshio, you should be able to easily make a switch in the future.

Out of all formats I know, VTU and XDMF are the ones I personally use most.

Answer (score 1):

Besides MSH file format cited in Wes's answer, I am also using Gamma3's MESH file format. If you are programming in C/C++, there is an easy-to-use software library, LM6, for loading/saving in this file format [1]

[1] https://www.rocq.inria.fr/gamma/gamma/Membres/CIPD/Loic.Marechal/Research/LM6.html

Answer (score 0):

I second the use of VTK for file output.
If you wish to use a very generic mesh structure, I would point you in the direction of the CGNS library (CFD General Notation System) which is an opensource mesh format with its own library that is maintained by a consortium (including Boeing and NASA). Reading a list of nodes, properties, boundary conditions, etc. is extremely useful with this library and the library itself is very easy to compile. The library is in C++, but it can be linked with Fortran.

We use it in our in-house code and I have found it is a very efficient format. It uses HDF5 under the hood for binary files. Furthermore, ANSYS, Salome, GMSH all support the exportation to this format at varying degree.
Here is the github:
https://cgns.github.io/